# Rename Json field "LVL2" to "ORG_LVL_1" in JOLT

Tags: arrays, json, mapping, transformation, jolt

Rename Json field "LVL2" to "ORG_LVL_1" in JOLT

```
[
  {
    "LVL2": "Co0053",
    "status": "Active"
  },
  {
    "LVL2": "Co0054",
    "status": "Active"
  }
]
```

Desired Output where ORG_LVL_2 is the modified/renamed JSON field which was previously LVL2 :

```
[
  {
    "ORG_LVL_2": "Co0053",
    "status": "Active"
  },
  {
    "ORG_LVL_2": "Co0054",
    "status": "Active"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of the following transformation specs :

1.

> ```json
> [
>  { // generate new attribute, namely "ORG_LVL_2"
>    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
>    "spec": {
>      "*": {
>        "ORG_LVL_2": "@(1,LVL2)"
>      }
>    }
>  },
>  { // delete the original attribute
>    "operation": "remove",
>    "spec": {
>      "*": {
>        "LVL2": ""
>      }
>    }
>  }  
> ]
> ```

or

2.

> ```json
> [
>  {
>    "operation": "shift",
>    "spec": {
>      "*": {
>        "*2": "[&1].ORG_&(0,1)_2", // use &(0,1) representation technique >to replicate the substring LVL; where 0 : the current level, 1 : the first >asterisk(indeed there's only single one)
>        "*": "[&1].&" // keep the other attribute fixed
>      }
>    }
>  }
> ]
> ```